# How to edit .reg file using batch script

Tags: batch-file, registry

I want to edit .reg file, before importing it by using batch script.
Content of .reg file given below.

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SomeSoftware]
>   Resource=**RESOURCE_FOLDER**/images

There are many keys like this in the file.
Here I want to replace **RESOURCE_FOLDER** with any directory path (like C:\Program Files\SomeSoftware\resource), which depends on user input.
For importing .reg file following command can be used

> regedit.exe /s path of .reg file

Can we provide arguments to this command which takes **RESOURCE_FOLDER** value ?
or any other way to do this ?

Comment: On using default export a .reg file is a UTF-16 encoded Unicode file with BOM containing in first line `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00` which is hard to modify in command line environment. But choosing on export `Win9x/NT4 Registration Files` in `Save as type` results in getting a .reg file being encoded in ANSI with first line being `REGEDIT4`. Such a single byte per character encoded .reg file is very easy to edit within a command line. `regedit.exe` imports both registry file types. So I suggest to use version type 4 for the .reg file.

Comment: For the replace in ANSI encoded .reg file with first line being REGEDIT4 see [How can you find and replace text in a file using the Windows command-line environment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/)

Comment: @Mofi : Will version type 4 work on Windows 8 ?